# Values stored in $_SESSION but showing in $_COOKIES array

Tags: javascript, php, session

I learnt from the internet that confidential information like *username* and *password* should be sent through `session` rather than `cookies`, as they are quite vulnerable.

**My HTML form which takes input:**

```
<body>
    <h2>Cafeteria registration</h2>
    <form class="details" method="POST">
        Full name: <input type="text" placeholder="Please avoid any kind of prefixes" id="name" size=25 oninput="login()"><br><br>
        Organization:<div id="org"><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" onclick="check()">ID no: <input type="number" id="org_number" style="visibility: hidden"><br><br>
                     <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" onclick="check()">Mobile No: <input type="tel" id="ph_number" style="visibility: hidden" required></div><br><br>
        
        E-mail: <input type="email" id="email" size=25><br><br>
        
    </form>
    <button id="button" style="background-color: whitesmoke">Register</button>
    <script src="back_end.js" async></script>
</body>
```

**Javascript which stores input from a html form:**

```
sessionStorage.setItem("name",document.getElementById("name").value);
sessionStorage.setItem("ID_No",document.getElementById("org_number").value);
sessionStorage.setItem("Mobile_No",document.getElementById("ph_number").value);
sessionStorage.setItem("Email",document.getElementById("email").value);
```

**PHP reads the values:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    var_dump($_SESSION); //This shows to be completely empty
    var_dump($_COOKIE);  //Surprisingly, all the values show in this array
?>
```

My `$_COOKIE` array is populated with the values, but my `$_SESSION`array is completely empty. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sessions are variable that only you can set it server side and that is your problem, you need to first pass them with the post method to one php file like this

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
```

and then get them in the php from the `$_POST` global variable and then save it from your php file like this f.e.

```php
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// Set session variables
$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST["name"];
```

And then you can see them with this code

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

This [like](https://www.guru99.com/cookies-and-sessions.html) will help you too to understand the difference between session and cookies

Answer (score 0):

`sessionStorage` does NOT store data in a server-side session variable. It stores data in on the client for the lifetime of the window/tab. JavaScript runs in the browser, not on the server (in your case at least). Learn more about session storage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Nor does `sessionStorage` set cookies. Your code must be setting those somewhere else.

Lastly, if you want to send user data over the wire (your form is a signup form, presumably), just use [`$_POST` variables](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_post.asp). The password shouldn't be stored anywhere but the database; it shouldn't even be logged.

Comment: I tried with `$_POST`, but it's empty too.